# Sending request from nestjs local server to another express local server giving connect ECONNREFUSED error

Tags: node.js, express, axios, localhost, nestjs

i am getting this error when i send a request from my nestjs local server to another express local server. can anyone help me with that? the other server is up and running fine, i tested the express server from the postman, and its working fine but when i try to send a request from nestjs, it's giving me this error. Also the error is only coming when i access localhost, otherwise its working fine

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z71TL.png)

[Working code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWVzl.png)

[Not working code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbDY5.png)

Comment: Probably it is something with CORS. Make sure that you have configured CORS middleware at server

Comment: it's not. I have configured cors middleware at the express server but still, it doesn't work

Comment: Post code instead of screenshots